# Bulk user creation

Tags: users, drush

We manually create users via the Acquia Cloud Sites Factory. I want to create a script that bulk creates users at one time using a .csv file with just username, email, and password.

I know I can use a command like `drush ucrt username —password password1 —mail test@example.com`, but I need to create multiple users at the same time.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which drupal version ?

Comment: Using Drupal 8 on Acquia

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a shell-script to stick the `drush ucrt`-command in a loop reading from the `.csv`-file.
2. If you're on Drupal 7, use contributed module [**User Import**](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_import).

Comment: Ok, not sure how to incorporate drush into the script

Comment: I figured creating multiple users from a .csv would require a loo, right

Comment: 1) *drush* is a command like any other CLI-command. you just put the command line containing the drush-command on a line in the script; 2) I've no idea why you would require a [loo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loo)

Comment: Well I need to create multiple users at the same time using a .csv file.

Comment: *Both* methods I've suggested to you will create multiple users at the same time using a .cvs file.

Answer (score 0):

If you working with drupal 7 you can use [User Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_import)
 module. Import users into Drupal, or update existing users, with data from a CSV file (comma separated file). Provides a wide range of features out of the box, and a comprehensive API to customise imports.

**Features**

Create an account for each user

Update existing users option (data can be added or replaced)

**Upload Options**

Upload CSV files through browser

Use file uploaded through SFTP, FTP,...

Drop an import file into a directory to trigger an automatic import

Comment: Using Drupal 8, so I guess User Import won't work.